# How to make jQuery active state ignore uppercase or lowercase for url detection

Tags: javascript, jquery, navigation

This is my code to make active state working, the probleme is it's case sensitive. Example, let's say you click on one of the menu tab, you get the active state working but if you try to change manually the url to not have let's say uppercase then it won't work.

How to make the script works so that case sensitivity is not considered when checking the href agains what's in the URL?

Thanks all!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("ul#menu li a").wrapInner("<span></span>");
    $("ul#menu li a span").css({
        "opacity": 0
    });
$("ul#menu li a").hover(function() {
    $(this).children("span").animate({
        "opacity": 1
    }, 400);
}, function() {
    $(this).children("span").animate({
        "opacity": 0
    }, 400);
});
}); /**ACTIVE STATE SCRIPT**/
$(function() {
    var pathname = window.location.pathname;
    var page = pathname.match(/\/([^\/]+\.[^\/]+)/i)[1];
    var target = $('#menu a').filter(function() {
    console.log($(this).attr('href'), page);
    return $(this).attr('href').toLowerCase().indexOf(page.toLowerCase()) > -1;
});
    $(target).addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: compare both using `toLowerCase()`.

Answer (score 1):

First of, change your regexp to that :

```
var page = pathname.match(/\/([^\/]+\.[^\/]+)/i)[1];
```

Then your selector :

```
var target = $('#menu a').filter(function(){
    return $(this).attr('href').toLowerCase().indexOf(page.toLowerCase()) > -1;
});
```

Comment: Will that work?  That would not set the `page` variable to a lowercase version of the value in `pathname`, it would just ignore the case when it was doing the `match`.  Wouldn't you need to do this: `var pathname = window.location.pathname.toLowerCase();` in order to get the `pathname` (and `page`) values to be lowercase?

Comment: @talemyn You are absolutly right, my mistake. Thanks

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon could you please edit your code to make it work as per talemyn recommendations? Thanks!

Comment: I updated it @LyesD . . . that should be what you need.

Comment: @talemyn i already had it updated (look at the argument of `indexOf`).

Comment: Ahh . . . my bad, @Karl-AndréGagnon . . . I missed the update.  Apologies.   :)

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon Ok Karl it's not working for me, I've edited my original code above to include yours. Let me know if that's right.

Comment: @LyesD in the filter function, make a console.log of both the href and the `page`. Tell me what it log.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon How would you do that? Sorry for being a noob! :)

Comment: `var target = $('#menu a').filter(function(){
console.log($(this).attr('href'), page);
    return $(this).attr('href').toLowerCase().indexOf(page.toLowerCase()) > -1;
});`

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon Here a screenshot of the console log : http://www.lyesdehili.com/ConsoleLog.png

Comment: @LyesD the condition should be true, but you have an other error not related to your code...

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon I've updated my code above so you can see the whole code that makes my menu work. Let me know if you see anything wrong. Thanks a lot Karl.

Comment: @LyesD As you can see here (http://jsfiddle.net/JwR2g/) the script should be working, but your log show `gt is not defined`. Yet i don't see any var `gt` being use. You should find where the var is used...